# help fixing pagination class

Tags: php, oop, pagination

here is my pagination class. the data in the construct is just an another class that does db queries and other stuff. the problem that i am having is that i cant seem to get the data output to match the pagination printing and i cant seem to get the mysql_fetch_assoc() to query the data and print it out. i get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /phpdev/pagination/index.php on line 215
```

i know that can mean that the query isnt correct for it to fetch the data but i have entered it correctly. sorry for the script being a little long. i thank all in advance for any help.

```
<?php
include_once("class.db.php");
mysql_connect("host","login","password");
mysql_select_db("iadcart");

class Pagination {

        var $adjacents;
        var $limit; 
        var $param; 
        var $mPage; 
        var $query; 
        var $qData;
        var $printData;
        protected $db;


        function __construct() {
            $this->db = new MysqlDB;
        }


        function show() {
            $result = $this->db->query($this->query);
            $totalPages = $this->db->num_rows($result);
            $limit = $this->limit;

            /* -------------------------------------
                 Set Page
               ------------------------------------- */

            if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
                $page = intval($_GET['page']);
                $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
            } else {
                $start = 0;
            }



            /* -------------------------------------
                Set Page Vars
               ------------------------------------- */

            if($page == 0) {
                $page = 1;
            }

            $prev = $page - 1;
            $next = $page + 1;
            $lastPage = ceil($totalPages/$limit);
            $lpm1 = $lastPage - 1;
            $adjacents = $this->adjacents;
            $mPage = $this->mPage;

            //the magic
            $this->qData = $this->query . " LIMIT $start, $limit";
            $this->printData = $this->db->query($this->qData);

            /* -------------------------------------
                Draw Pagination Object
               ------------------------------------- */

            $pagination = "";
            if($lastPage > 1) {
                $pagination .= "<div class='pagination'>";
            }


            /* -------------------------------------
                Previous Link
               ------------------------------------- */

        if($page > 1) {
            $pagination .= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=$prev'> previous </a></li>";
        } else {
            $pagination .= "<li class='previous-off'> previous </li>";
        }


        /* -------------------------------------
            Page Numbers (not enough pages - just display active page)
           ------------------------------------- */

            if($lastPage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) {
                for($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastPage; $counter++) {
                    if($counter == $page) {
                        $pagination .= "<li class='active'>$counter</li>";
                    } else {
                        $pagination .= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                    }
                }


            }


        /* -------------------------------------
               Page Numbers (enough pages to paginate)
           ------------------------------------- */ 

        elseif($lastPage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)) {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $page) {
                        $pagination.= "<li class='active'>$counter</li>";
                    }
                    else {
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";   
                    }               
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=$lastPage'>$lastPage</a></li>";     
            }




            elseif($lastPage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))  {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=1'>1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=2'>2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $page) {
                        $pagination.= "<li class='active'>$counter</li>";
                    }
                    else {
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";   
                    }               
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=$lastPage'>$lastPage</a></li>";     
            }



            else {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=1'>1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "</li><a href='$mPage?page=2'>2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastPage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastPage; $counter++)  {

                        if ($counter == $page) {
                            $pagination.= "<li class='active'>$counter</li>";
                        }
                        else {
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";   
                        }

                    }
                }
            }



            /* -------------------------------------
                Next Link
               ------------------------------------- */
            if ($page < $counter - 1) {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='$mPage?page=$next'> Next </a></li>";
            }
            else {
                $pagination.= "<li class='next-off'> Next </li>";
            $pagination.= "</div>"; 
            }

            print $pagination;
        }






        }


?>          
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <table style="width:800px;">

    <?php


    mysql_connect("localhost","root","games818");
    mysql_select_db("iadcart");

    $pagination = new pagination;
    $pagination->adjacents = 3;
    $pagination->limit = 10;
    $pagination->param = $_GET['page'];
    $pagination->mPage = "index.php";
    $pagination->query = "select * from tbl_products where pVisible = 'yes'";


    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pagination->printData)) {
        print $row['pName'];
    }




    ?>

    </table>

    <br/><br/>

    <?php $pagination->show(); ?>






</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$pagination->printData` gets set in the `show()` function, but you are calling that function **after** your `while` loop, so there is no query result in `$pagination->printData` yet when you are using it in your `while` loop.

Comment: oh, but how else would i do this? $this->qData = $this->query . " LIMIT $start, $limit";
$this->printData = $this->db->query($this->qData); i want to be able to write something like $pagination->getData into the while loop so that i just write the query one time and the class takes care of paginating and displaying data.

Comment: It seems to me that the while loop needs to be inside the show() function.